# How to access element in Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I am trying to set the element's css property top base on it's height. To do it I create a directive like this:

```
directive('errormsgbox', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: false,
        replace:true,
        templateUrl: 'submitter/reports/errormsgbox.html',
        link: function(scope,element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        console.log(element[0].offsetHeight);   

                },2000);
            },2000)    
        }
    };
})
```

Directive Html:

```
<span ng-if='expenses.hasBlockers || expenses.hasWarnigs' style='border:1px solid gray' ng-show='policyViolation && showpencil' class='msgbox'>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='policymsg in expenses.policyMsg'>
            <span class='floatleft' ng-class="showPolicyClass(policymsg.type)">{{policymsg.type}} - </span><span style='width:285px;' class='floatleft'>{{policymsg.message}}</span>
            <div class='clear'></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Main Html:

```
<td class="text-center" style='position:relative'>
    <errormsgbox></errormsgbox>
</td>// it is in a table cell, the content of directive is from ng-repeat in this table
```

I need to access `<span>`.but as you can see, directive works fine it will show the correct info, but every time it will log `undefined` for element height. any idea How can I access this?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the page that has the directive you want to access and click 'Inspect Element', then enter:

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

in your developer console. This lets you access all the data in your angular scope. This will help debug the data that angular is using. But, in more direct answer to your question, I have done something similar where I set css properties inside a directive. It would turn your code into something like this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: false,
    replace:true,
    templateUrl: 'submitter/reports/errormsgbox.html',
    link: function(scope,element,attr) {
        element.css({
                    width: '360px',
                    height: '640px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    background: '#FFF'
                }); 
    }
};
```

Comment: cool feature indeed, but this does not necessarily answer the question

Answer (score 1):

For  `E` directives such as `<my-dir></my-dir>` the default `display` value will set to `inline`. You can do a few things here, either leverage block elements with `replace: true` or simply set a style rule, in this example,  `my-dir { display: block }`. You could even call `elem.css('display', 'block')` in your directive `link` function.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9t0oab04/) - simplified demo

---

Keep in mind `float` rules along with `inline-block` will take margins and padding into consideration for examining `offsetHeight`

Comment: In your example, yes, it works, but if I loop data into li with ng-repeat in your example, it gives me 0, I think the link function get run before the data loops in, that is why there are no content in the directive. which returns 0 as height.

Comment: ah okay, just wrap it in a `$timeout` then. I didn't include it in my fiddle example

Comment: yah it works in your example,but as you can see, I did try to wrap them with timeout in my code, but it returns undefined....it drives me crazy...

Comment: did you add the `display` rule in your code e.g. `errormsgbox { display: block }`?

Comment: also which browser are you using?

Comment: @vp_arth I can see the `ng-repeat` in the directive template. Can you explain a bit what you mean by that?

Comment: @linyuanxie nevermind that rule wouldn't work I see your `replace: true` on there. Hm, odd. Are you targeting the directive template with the `display` rule?

Comment: yes, the data of this directive is naste ng-repeat. as you can see in main html, I use this directive in a table cell, which use ng-repeat in the parent level<tr> and once it reach the directive, I need to do ng-repeat again.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztdogcee/) - it's weird - if we add `list-style: none` - we lose out height! It's back if we take it out. I am guessing you have this rule, is that true? very weird

Comment: well at least you can return 0, but in my case it returns undefind! any guess for this?

Comment: no that's very weird as well that is why I was curious to which browser you are using. Also, here is my last crack at it: [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/argarq75/). I changed the parent `<span>` to `inline-block`. Perhaps we'll need to keep at this but I'm admittedly very confused alongside you lol

Comment: I use chrome. it shouldn't be browser's problem. My confuse is why it returns undefined instead of 0. it means it didn't get this element at all!

Comment: would you be able to reproduce a fiddle or plunker by any chance?

Comment: ok, if I get rid of ng-if in my directive, it will return 0, I think this may be the problem... ng-if doing trick here....